# How do I use redis in node.js?

Tags: node.js, redis

I am trying to use redis using this segment of code:

```
const redis = require('redis');
const client = redis.createClient();
```

I am getting the following error:

```
events.js:174
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^

Error: Redis connection to 127.0.0.1:6379 failed - connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379
at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1097:14)
```

Comment: Is redis running on your system?

Comment: I added with: npm i --save redis

Comment: You need to run a redis server on your machine to be able to connect to it from javascript.

Comment: I did redis-server but the command is not recognized. What am I supposed to do?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to first install redis on your system. To do so, follow the instructions [here](https://redis.io/topics/quickstart).

Then run the following command in your command prompt/terminal:

`redis-server`

If you want to run redis in the background without having to start it everytime, then you can use:

`redis-server --daemonize yes`

You can check if your server is running by using the command:

`redis-cli set a 3` & `redis-cli get a`

If this works then your redis server has started successfully. 
After this, your previous code should be able to connect to the redis-server provided the server is running on the default port (6379).

Comment: what OS are you using? Have you installed redis successfully? Maybe it is just a matter of adding the redis-path in your .bashrc/PATH variable

Comment: That seems to work. I had downloaded redis using npm but it has to be downloaded as a Window service using msi. If you would like to write out your answer I will be glad to check it. There are tons of the same question on StackOverflow with no correct answer.